# Why do different ConsoleColor values display with the same rendered color in my console?

Tags: c#, colors, console-application

The game i've been making has a weird issue when I test it on my new laptop (a lenovo ideapad 530s). When I want to draw something with `Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.Green`, It has the exact same color as when I use `Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.Darkgreen`. I wrote this little program:

```
Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Test");
Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

When I run it, it shows the word "Test" twice, but both are in dark green.
When I run the following program:

```
Console.Foregroundcolor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

It writes "Test" in Dark green. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console that runs the application dictates what the actual colors to render are. "Green" and "DarkGreen" are just suggestions. Go to the properties of CMD to see what the actual color hex values are.

[image]

[image]